# XSLT transformation for namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">
         <NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">

            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:New>
                  <NS2:Pharmacy>
                     <NS2:Identification>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                            <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                             </NS2:Identification>
                             </NS2:Pharmacy>
                    </NS2:New>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:send>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have this xml which is on schema version 3.0 http://www.test.com/Service/v3 . I need to downgrade it to version 1 http://www.test.com/Service/v1. To do that i am using a XSL to transform it.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
            xmlns:booga="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3"
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:src="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT"
        > 


        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>

           </xsl:copy>

         </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="tns:*">
            <!-- Output a new element in the new namespace -->
            <xsl:element name="tns:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.test.com/Service/v1">
              <!-- Copy all child attributes and nodes 
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> -->
            <xsl:apply-templates  />
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

but i get a result like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">
         <NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">

            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:New>
                  <NS2:Pharmacy>
                     <NS2:Identification>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                            <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                         </NS2:Identification>
                         </NS2:Pharmacy>
                    </NS2:New>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:send>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In my output XML i get this

```
<NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT"   xmlns:tns="http://eps.pdxinc.com/webservice/Rxservice/v3">
```

**Why was this added to the `NS2:Message`?**

```
xmlns:tns="http://eps.pdxinc.com/webservice/Rxservice/v3
```

**It was not there in the input xml.**

There is something which I am missing. I would really appreciate if someone could point out the issue.

What I  am looking to create in the output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v1">
            <NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" >

                <NS2:Body>
                    <NS2:New>
                        <NS2:Pharmacy>
                            <NS2:Identification>
                                <NS2:ID>
                                    <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                                    <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                                    <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                                    <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                                </NS2:ID>
                            </NS2:Identification>
                        </NS2:Pharmacy>
                    </NS2:New>
                </NS2:Body>
            </NS2:Message>
        </tns:send>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The XSL document I am applying is adding an extra namespace  `xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3` in the `NS2:Message`.

Orginally the tag was :

```
<NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">
```

After i applied XSL it changed to :

```
<NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3>
```

I don't know where this namespace is getting added.

All I wanted was to transform `xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3` to `xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3` in `tns:send` tag.

Comment: Guest, You forgot to show the exact wanted result. Please , edit the question and specify this missing and important information.

Comment: Also, the provided XML isn't wellformed XML document. Please, correct.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the output xml i am looking for, The XML is now well formed. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

**XML Input**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">
            <NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">

                <NS2:Body>
                    <NS2:New>
                        <NS2:Pharmacy>
                            <NS2:Identification>
                                <NS2:ID>
                                    <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                                    <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                                    <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                                    <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                                </NS2:ID>
                            </NS2:Identification>
                        </NS2:Pharmacy>
                    </NS2:New>
                </NS2:Body>
            </NS2:Message>
        </tns:send>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (or 2.0 if you change the version)

(**Edit**: Changed "tns" prefix to "djh" to illustrate how the prefix doesn't matter.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:djh="http://www.test.com/Service/v3"
    xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="djh:*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.test.com/Service/v1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v1">
         <NS2:Message xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" release="006" version="010">
            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:New>
                  <NS2:Pharmacy>
                     <NS2:Identification>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                           <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                     </NS2:Identification>
                  </NS2:Pharmacy>
               </NS2:New>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:send>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Awesome !! What are we actually doing here: <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:template>

Comment: @Guest - That template is matching elements other than `tns:*`. By doing that match and using `xsl:element`, we avoid any other xmlns being output. Also, `name()` includes the original namespace prefix.

Comment: +1 great answer. A slight improvement to make it 100% safe would be to change the template for `*` to use `@namespace` and specify the element's `namespace-uri()`: `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
` Almost all XSLT engines will use the namespace-prefix from `@name`, but don't have to according to the spec. In XSLT 1.0 "XSLT processors may make use of the prefix of the QName specified in the name attribute when selecting the prefix used for outputting the created element as XML; however, they are not required to do so." http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#element-element

Comment: What if i dont know the namespace prefix, in this case 'tns' and still i want to change all instances of
string http://www.test.com/Service/v3 to http://www.test.com/Service/v1

Comment: @Guest - The prefix doesn't matter. You can use whatever you like. I edited my answer to use the prefix `djh` instead of `tns` to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks mate, my issue was that I wasn't adding "namespace" tag and value in  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.test.com/Service/v1"> line